# What is the syntax to pass a list to ack?

Tags: ack, strawberry-perl, chocolatey

I have installed strawberry-perl on my windows 7 laptop.

I want to search for a list of words using `grep` or `ack` on windows. 
I have been able to perform basic searches using ack, but I just don't know how to pass a list of words to `ack` So I want to pass a list of words to ack and find out the line numbers where these words occur. Both words do not have to occur on the same line.

For example, if I am searching for "doll" and "house", I could have doll on line 12 and house on line 244.

I tried something like this `ack "doll"|"house"` but it throws the following error.

```
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:22
+ ack "doll" | "house" <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying you want to find all the files where "doll" appears and where "house" appears.  So here's what you do.

First, find all the files that contain "doll", and print a list of them.

```
ack -l doll
```

Then search that list of files for the word "house".

```
ack house $(ack -l doll)
```

Or, if you're not running a shell that lets you do that (i.e. Windows), you can do:

```
ack -l doll | ack -x house
```

`ack -x` says "Take the list of files to search from STDIN".

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Hopefully I still have this setup on the desktop.